# Sort a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been searching this and other websites for an answer for more than two hours now and can't find a sort function that seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
{

    $ratingsArrayCounter = 0;
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $ratingsArray = array();

    if ($nrows > 0){
        for ($i=0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
            $ratingsArray[$i]->autoID=$row->autoID;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->awareness=$row->awareness;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->performance=$row->performance;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->attendance=$row->attendance;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->attention=$row->attention;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->knowledge=$row->knowledge;

            $ratingsArray[$i]->ratingsAverage = rand(0, 100);
            $ratingsArrayCounter++;
        }
    }

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['ratingsAverage'] - $b['ratingsAverage'];
}

usort($ratingsArray, 'sortByOrder')
?>
```

The output is not coming out sorted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason for not sorting with SQL?

Comment: What do you want to achive with your sorting? Off my head I can tell you that `$ratingsArray[$i]->autoID` should not work since `$ratingsArray` is an array and not an object.

Comment: Why is there an opening brace `{` immediately below `<?php`? I don't see its corresponding closing brace. Is this the full code you're using?

Comment: @AgustinMeriles for integers it will do the same ... return a number greater then 0 if a > b less then if a<b and 0 if they are the same.

Comment: @byf-ferdy `$ratingsArray[$i]->autoID` will work, `$ratingsArray[$i]` is an object (thus `$ratingsArray` is an array of objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though my answer was accepted, this answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972904/1560865

---

Here's a quote from the [`usort` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> **Caution**
>
> Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as
>   float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's
>   return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an
>   integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

Therefore: If you are not particularly interested about the correct order for rows whose `ratingsAverage` only differs after the 5th decimal place, a quick-and-dirty solution could be this:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return ($a->ratingsAverage - $b->ratingsAverage) * 10000;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Actually, now after its edit [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16972904/1560865) is better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

**Bad**

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['ratingsAverage'] - $b['ratingsAverage'];
}
```

**Good**

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a->ratingsAverage - $b->ratingsAverage;
}
```

P.S. If you aren't seeing errors from trying to use those objects like arrays, turn on/up your error reporting and be sure to display errors (search if you're unsure how, it's beyond the scope of this question).

---

**Edit** for floats, use the more usual `if-elseif-else` pattern for `usort()` callbacks. The `a - b` example cannot be used because the function *must* return an integer.

As stated in the [manual page for `usort()`](http://php.net/usort):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    if ($a->ratingsAverage > $b->ratingsAverage) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($a->ratingsAverage < $b->ratingsAverage) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers.

After using this updated function, it seems my problem is with trying to sort decimals.  When I sort whole numbers, it sorts just fine.

Any idea's how to get this to sort decimals?

Comment: @MicahVanHuss see my edit for a note about floats.

Answer (score 0):

Though sorting it directly in the database should be the prefered solution, another php-based solution would to create another array that maps each `$ratingsArray` member index directly to its `raitingsAverage`, sort that array and use the new key order to access the `$ratingsArray`. Here's some example code:

```
<?php
{

    $ratingsArrayCounter = 0;
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $ratingsArray = array();
    $sortingHelper = array();

    if ($nrows > 0){
        for ($i=0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
            $ratingsArray[$i]->autoID=$row->autoID;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->awareness=$row->awareness;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->performance=$row->performance;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->attendance=$row->attendance;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->attention=$row->attention;
            $ratingsArray[$i]->knowledge=$row->knowledge;

            $ratingsArray[$i]->ratingsAverage = rand(0, 100);
            $sortingHelper[$i] = $ratingsArray[$i]->ratingsAverage;
            $ratingsArrayCounter++;
        }
    }

    asort($sortingHelper);
    $sortedKeys = array_keys($sortingHelper);

    // To access the sorted version of the $ratingsArray,
    // you would then do something like this:
    echo($ratingsArray[$sortedKeys[$i]]->knowledge);

    // If you really need the sorted array, you could
    // also do something like this:
    $sortedRatingsArray = array();
    foreach($sortedKeys as $key) {
        $sortedRatingsArray[] = $ratingsArray[$key];
    }
?>
```